# Add shading to a gantt chart to delineate weekends

Tags: r, ggplot2, gantt-chart

I have created a gantt chart using ggplot, code below:

```
# load packages
require("ggplot2")
require("reshape2")

###############################################################################

# Create list of tasks name strings.
tasks <- c("Write introduction", "Parse citation data",
           "Construct data timeline",
           "Write methods", "Model formulation", 
           "Model selection", "Write results", "Write discussion",
           "Write abstract and editing")

# Compile dataframe of task names, and respective start and end dates.
dfr <- data.frame(
  name = factor(tasks, levels = tasks),
  start.date = as.Date(c("2018-04-09", "2018-04-09", "2018-04-16",
                         "2018-04-30", "2018-04-16", "2018-05-21",
                         "2018-06-04", "2018-07-02", "2018-07-30")),
  end.date = as.Date(c("2018-04-30", "2018-04-20", "2018-05-18",
                       "2018-06-01", "2018-05-18", "2018-06-01",
                       "2018-06-29", "2018-07-27", "2018-08-31"))
)

# Merge start and end dates into durations.
mdfr <- melt(dfr, measure.vars = c("start.date", "end.date"))

###############################################################################

# Create gantt chart.

ggplot(mdfr, aes(value, name)) +
  geom_line(size=4) +
  xlab(NULL) +
  ylab(NULL) +
  ggtitle("Project gantt chart") +
  theme_minimal() +
  theme(aspect.ratio = 0.3, axis.text = element_text(size = 10))
```

How would one go about formatting the chart so that weekends are shaded on the background or delineated on the background grid?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

First you need to get weekday information:

```
foo <- as.Date(mdfr$value)
# Generate days from first to last day
allDays <- seq(min(foo), max(foo), by = "days")
# Extract weekday
days <- data.frame(day = weekdays(allDays), date = allDays)
```

Add `geom_vline` (vertical lines) on weekends:

```
library(ggplot2)

ggplot(mdfr) +
    geom_vline(data = subset(days, day %in% c("Saturday", "Sunday")),
              aes(xintercept = date), color = "grey80", size = 2) +
    geom_line(aes(value, name), size = 4) +
    labs(title = "Project gantt chart",
         x = NULL,
         y = NULL) +
    theme_minimal() +
    theme(aspect.ratio = 0.3, 
          axis.text = element_text(size = 10))
```

[image]

Comment: Worked perfectly! Thank you!

Answer (score 2):

You can try

```
library(tidyverse)
mdfr %>% 
  as.tibble() %>% 
  mutate(date=as.POSIXct(value)) %>% 
  ggplot(aes(date, name)) +
  geom_line(size=4) +
  xlab(NULL) +
  ylab(NULL) +
  ggtitle("Project gantt chart") +
  theme_minimal() +
  theme(aspect.ratio = 0.3, axis.text = element_text(size = 10)) +
  scale_x_datetime(date_minor_breaks = "7 day") + 
  theme(panel.grid.minor.x = element_line(size=2, color = "pink"))
```

[image]

The idea is to transform `value` into `POSIXct` format (I'm using `tidyverse` here. But it is not necessary), then you can specify in `scale_x_datetime` minor breaks with `"7 days`. They start every Saturday. Using a bigger size will cover Sundays as well.

Comment: Very nice solution!

Comment: @PoGibas the problem is when minor hits a major gridline. Then the minor is not shown. So far no solution. But must be possible. ;)

Comment: Maybe remove minor lines?